# Linked List Insert and Delete Doesn't work for the same id

Tags: c, struct, file-io, linked-list

I'm trying to write some functions where you can insert a student(name, id) in the list and delete him. If the student is already in the list and i delete him and then try to insert him again the program outputs: `Student added successfuly` but he doesn't appear in the list. When i run the program again and i try to insert him (this time he doesn't exist in the list) the program works fine. Note that everything is based on the student's id and not his name. Here are the functions:

```
int addStudent(student st, list l){

    if (findStudent(st->id, l) == NULL)
    {
        list_push_back(l, st->name, st->id);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

student findStudent(int id, list l){
    student stTemp = l->head;

    if (l->size != 0)
    {
        while (stTemp != NULL)
        {
            if (stTemp->id == id)//check if the student's id is the same as the student's id in the struct
            {
                return stTemp;
            }
            stTemp = stTemp->next; 
        }

    }

    return NULL;
}

list list_push_back(list l, char *name, int id)
{
    student new_student = malloc(sizeof(struct studentR));
    if (new_student == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }


    strcpy(new_student->name, name);
    new_student->id = id;
    new_student->next = NULL;

    if (list_isempty(l))
    {
        l->head = new_student;
    }
    else
    {
        l->tail->next = new_student;
    }
    l->tail = new_student;
    l->size++;

    return l;
}

int deleteStudent(student st, list l){
    //check if the list is empty
    if (list_isempty(l))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //check if the student is in the list
    st = findStudent(st->id, l);
    if (st == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    student temp = l->head;
    student prev = temp;    
    //if student to be deleted is the first in the list
    if (l->head->id == st->id)
    {
        l->head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        l->size--;

        return 1;
    }

    //if student to be deleted is the last in the list
    if (l->tail == st->next)
    {
        while (temp->id != st->id)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        prev->next = NULL;
        l->tail = prev;
        free(temp);
        l->size--;

        return 1;
    }


    while (temp->id != st->id)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    l->size--;

    return 1;
}
```

I'm basically trying to insert->delete->insert the same node

Comment: You ought always to develop new functionality in isolation as much as possible; write a linked list for a Student that contains only an int, and get that working perfectly before you attempt to add a string.

Comment: You are right. I didn't even think of that. But i'm closing in on the deadline could you help me with this? It's ok if you don't want

Comment: I'll take a crack at it, but 1) you haven't posted a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which makes things difficult, and 2) you seem to have ignored a lot of compiler errors and warnings.

Comment: I solved it. I just changed some bits of code in the list_push_back function and now it seems to be working fine. Also I'm not getting any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the list_push_back function and it works, for now XD.

```
//enters the new student in the end of the list
list list_push_back(list l, char *name, int id)
{
    student new_student = malloc(sizeof(struct studentR));
    if (new_student == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }


    strcpy(new_student->name, name);
    new_student->id = id;
    new_student->next = NULL;

    student tmp = l->head;
    if (list_isempty(l))
    {
        l->head = new_student;
    }
    else
    {
        while (tmp->next!=NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = new_student;
    }
    l->tail = new_student;
    l->size++;

    return l;
}
```

Comment: I called part of your code "broken" in a comment which I then deleted because the word was too strong for what looked like a memory leak. What you now have is a risk of *undefined behavior.* This solution may be good enough to satisfy the person who gave you the assignment, but if you want to become a stronger coder you must demand more from yourself.